# modulation depth

Tags: frequency, modulation, amplitude, signal-power, amplitude-modulation

When a value for the power dissipated by an AM signal is given, and the depth of modulation is also given. Then you are told to find the modulation depth required to increase the power to a higher value.

Which formulae will you use? Please explain with  example.

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: I have edited it. Please someone should answer me

Comment: You added no improvement with respect to anything we've said. Instead, you just removed facts from the question.

Comment: @JaskyObi The power of an AM signal depends on the power amplifier used to transmit it. There's no one-to-one relationship between modulation index and signal power in general.